# jQuery menu not working ie (Document Mode : Quirks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

below code not working with internet explorer document mode quirks each time length of the sub menu double when mouseover on it. ... please help ..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
      <div id="megaStore">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>Products
            <ul>
              <li>Furniture
                <ul>
                  <li>Tables & Chairs</li>
                  <li>Sofas</li>
                  <li>Occasional Furniture</li>
                  <li>Childerns Furniture</li>
                  <li>Beds</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#menu").kendoMenu();
        });
       </script>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would it be in quirks mode if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: ... and now it doesn't have a doctype?

Comment: Did you try the  latest release  of KendoUI. They have fixed a lot of bugs.

Comment: Yes i removed it ... @BoltClock actually it need to work with Quirks mode without the doctype... actual code in the panel of large code i don't have access to edit the header.. that's why i remove the doctype...(this is a sample)

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI doesn't support IE Quirks mode. IE renders the content with its IE5.5 engine when in this mode, which is broken even more than the IE6 mode.

Check the Supported Browsers section on the Kendo UI site:
[Kendo UI Demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/), and the documentation: [Technical Requirements](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/technical-requirements)